# jQuery show loading while generating excel report no ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loading

I have a form which has a Date From and To Date selector then a generate button, upon clicking generate button, an excel file will be the output. Question how and where do I put the loading script in my code given I'm not using ajax but rather:

```
$("#btnReport1").click(function() {
    var page = 'export-report1?from='+$("#fromDateAll").val()+'&to='+$("#toDateAll").val();
    return window.location = page;
});
```

And my route

```
Route::get('export-report1', 'ReportController@exportReport1');
```

function

```
public function exportReport1()
{
  $from  = Input::get('from');
  $to    = Input::get('to');

  $query = "SELECT id, phone FROM qcv.forms WHERE calldatetime >= '$from' AND calldatetime <= '$to' ORDER BY id ASC ;";
  // $query = "SELECT a.id as form_id, a.phone, b.metrics_id, b.response, c.metrics_name, c.description, c.question
  //     FROM forms a
  //     INNER JOIN forms_responses b ON a.id = b.form_id
  //     INNER JOIN metrics c ON c.id = b.metrics_id LIMIT 10";


  $phone = DB::connection('mysql')->select($query);

  if(!empty($phone))
  {


      Excel::create('Laravel Excel', function($excel) use ($phone) {

      return  $excel->sheet('Excel sheet', function($sheet) use ($phone) {

              $sheet->setOrientation('landscape');

              $sheet->cell('A9', 'KEY QUALITY METRICS');
              $sheet->cell('B9', 'DESCRIPTIONS');
              $sheet->cell('C9', 'ASSESSMENT QUESTION');

              $sheet->cells('A9:C9', function($cells) {
                    $cells->setFontWeight('bold');
                    $cells->setFontColor('#DF013A');
                });

                    $metrics = Metric::all();
                    $metric_start = 10;
                    $start = "D";
                    $count = 10;
                    foreach ($phone as $key => $value2) // Populate Phone Numbers Horizontally
                    {
                        $sheet->cell($start.'9', $value2->phone);
                        // This will fill the responses for each number
                        foreach ($metrics as $key => $value)
                        {
                            $responses = FormResponses::where('form_id', '=', $value2->id)->where('metrics_id', '=', $value->id)->get();
                            $sheet->cell($start.$count, $responses[0]->response);
                            $sheet->cell('C'.$count, $value->question);
                            $sheet->cell('B'.$count, $value->description);
                            $sheet->cell('A'.$count, $value->metrics_name);
                           $count++;
                        }
                        $start++;
                        $count = 10;
                    }
          });

      })->export('xls');
  }
  else
  {
    return "No records found.";
  }

}
```

Comment: You will need to do this with AJAX. That's the cleanest approach.

Comment: @Shreyas nope. Can't be unless you add some tricks like making an iframe and passing url in there which i don't want to do.

Comment: Why not open a new tab with that URL?

Comment: @Shreyas not appropriate. I need the page to show some loading spinner to let the users know that the data still processing. opening another tab without them knowing whats going is not ideal i guess.

Comment: So how I would do this, is to show the loading animation and make an AJAX call for generating the Excel file  and storing it someplace. Then this URL is returned in the AJAX call. Once I get the URL, I hide the loading animation, and then set the URL as window.location.